# Eclipse regex for "everything between"

Tags: regex, eclipse, string, replace

I have been trawling through documentation and posts in stackoverflow on this but can't seem to get the syntax right. I want replace everything between the `return` keyword and trailing `;` in something like this:

```
return new Foo() {

    void bar(){
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
};
```

This is my most informed attempt so far but it doesn't work: `return(.*?);`

Any help much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "dot matches new line" switch `(?s)` and look-arounds:

```
(?s)(?<=return).*?(?=;)
```

This entire regex matches anything between *but not including* `return` and `;` across multiple lines.